# Multiple $lookup in aggregate some are 1 to 1 and others 1 to many

Tags: mongodb

I got 3 tables: booking, users, expenses

One booking can have only one user but several expenses

How do I make an aggregate that gets records containing....

- fields about the booking
- fields about the user
- array with fields about the expenses

I tried this:

```
bookingTable.aggregate([
    {                                                           
        $match: {                                               
            status  : { $in: [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9 ] },
            checkin : { $gte: fromDate, $lte: toDate }
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "users",
            localField: "user",
            foreignField: "_id",    
            as: "users"     
        }   
    },
    {
        $unwind: { path:'$users', preserveNullAndEmptyArrays:true },
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "expense",
            localField: "_id",
            foreignField: "booking",    
            as: "expense"       
        }   
    },
    {
        $unwind: { path:'$expense', preserveNullAndEmptyArrays:true },
    },
    {
        $project: {
            "_id"           : 1,
            "checkin"       : 1,
            "checkout"      : 1,
            "price"         : 1,
            "tenantName"    : "$users.name",
            "tenantPhone"   : "$users.phone",
            "expenseNo"     : "$expense._id",
            "dueDate"       : "$expense.dueDate",
            "paidDate"      : "$expense.paidDate",
            "amount"        : "$expense.amount"
        }
    }
])
```

Right now I get one record for every expense,
instead of one record for every booking with an array of expenses

How do I get ONE record pr booking with its multiple expenses in an array?

Comment: The output of `$lookup` is **ALWAYS** an array of however many entries match or "none", as is the case for it's "LEFT JOIN" behavior. There are no exceptions. You can select the "first array element" or simply `$unwind` if you expect **one**. But there generally should be no need to `$unwind` **every** result. That's SQL relational thinking, and your thiinking instead needs to change. Just leave the "arrays" as is.

Comment: @NeilLunn but if I dont $unwind the expenses, then how can I select specific fields?  Hmmm..  but you might be correct here that its the $unwind that gives me 1 record pr expense instead of 1 record pr booking

Comment: @NeilLunn yep you were correct :) One more quick question if you dont mind. Lets say I did a lookup in **expense** using the field **booking.foo** which matches **expense.bar**.  This works great except I got 25,000 records in **expense** where **expense.bar** is blank.  So every record where **booking.foo** is blank will get these 25,000 records in an array.  Is there a way to make a "not blank" or "not undefined" or similar in a $lookup ?

Comment: Probably best to [post a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) for that, and just include a couple of sample documents to demonstrate what you mean, and what you expect to happen instead. Questions are better asked as "questions" rather than "comments" so you can include such details which make it really clear what you are asking.